# Replace particular characters from csv column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, duplicates

I have a csv file where I have already deleted the duplicates based on a certain criteria, now I want to replace '(' , ')' , '_' etc with ' ' in only the remarks column.

The CSV: [image: Input]

Note: 1. Please note the actual input has 10k rows and we cannot know what's between () or before/after , etc

2. The 'remarks' column contains string and I don't want to make a new output file, need changes in the same csv.

This what I have done till now:

```
#to delete duplicates based on criteria
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv", low_memory=False)
df2 = df[df["id"]==2]
result_df = df2.drop_duplicates(keep ='first')
result_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

This above code works fine.

```
#this is to replace characters only in the 'remarks' column
df3 = pd.read_csv("output.csv",encoding ='ISO-8859-1', low_memory=False)
df1 = df3[df3["remarks"]]
df1.replace(to_replace='(', value=' ', inplace = True)
df1.replace(to_replace=')', value=' ', inplace = True)
df1.replace(to_replace='/', value=' ', inplace = True)
df1.replace(to_replace='_', value=' ', inplace = True)
df1.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

This gives me an error-

```
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA/NaN values.
```

Answer (score 0):

First need compare column `remarks` by some value and then `replace` only this column if need processing same file by filtering by some values, e.g. here `id == 2`:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'remarks' : ['(someword)', '(someword)', 'xyz', '(ad_)'],
                   'id':[2,3,6,2]})

mask = df3["id"] == 2
df3.loc[mask, "remarks"] = df3.loc[mask, "remarks"].replace(r'[\(\)/_]', ' ', regex=True)
print (df3)
      remarks  id
0   someword    2
1  (someword)   3
2         xyz   6
3        ad     2
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, thanks for taking time to answer my question. Although the error is gone now but the issue is the code is not doing what it's supposed to do. For eg: if there's something like '(someword)' in the remarks column, the code is supposed to replace the '(' and ')' but it's not. That is, the output should have been ' someword ' but it's not replacing anything. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Can you add some data sample to question?

Comment: I have just edited my comment to give an example. Please have a look.

Comment: @Fanatic - What should do `df3[df3["remarks"]]` ?

Comment: have added a picture and note for your reference, if you could kindly take a look that would be great.

Comment: I have made some edits to the original post for your reference.

Comment: @Fanatic - So it means need remove `()_/` from row if `id=2` ?

Comment: @jazrael yes, but the issue if it's with a word like (aaaa) it's not replacing the starting ( and ending ).

Comment: @Fanatic - it is expected, because id==1 for (aaa)

Comment: yeah I was just explaining, so according to that the starting '(' and ending ')' (bbbb) is not being replaced. Moreover, another problem with your solution is that you are manually putting the 'remarks' content in df3. Imagine you have 10,000 rows, all with different names and remarks. That's the main issue, I can't manually put these values.

Comment: please have a look at my above comment.

Comment: @Fanatic - For me solution working well, not idea why your not.

Answer (score 0):

I used @jezrael data & modified his code a bit. Instead of creating `new` column, you can use existing column `remarks`

```
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame( {'name': ['jenna', 'cole', 'shyam', 'sam'],
                  'id': [1,2,3,1],
    'remarks' : ['hasyaya (aaa) hahaha', 'yhasyaya (bbb) zzzz', '(axyz) haaaa', 'axyz (zaaaa)'],
                   'id':[2,3,6,2]})
df['remarks'] = df.remarks.str.replace(r'[\(\)/_]', ' ', regex=True)
print(df)



    name  id               remarks
0  jenna   2  hasyaya  aaa  hahaha
1   cole   3   yhasyaya  bbb  zzzz
2  shyam   6           axyz  haaaa
3    sam   2          axyz  zaaaa
```

Comment: Hi @ragas,thanks for helping me, I have added a picture and note for your reference, if you could kindly take a look that would be great.

Comment: @Fanatic: I updated my answer based on your data.

Comment: Hey @ragas, the problem with your solution is that you are manually putting the 'names' and 'remarks' content in df. Imagine you have 10,000 rows, all with different names and remarks. That's the main issue, I can't manually put these values.

Comment: I'm creating the dataset manually because you put it as image (screenshot). Hopefully your data is not as image. Suppose your data is in csv file. Then read the csv file as pandas df & then run the code.

Comment: After reading the data as df, run `df['remarks'] = df.remarks.str.replace(r'[\(\)/_]', ' ', regex=True)`. This will replace `(,),` from `remarks` column.

Comment: this gives me an error saying "replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'regex')

Comment: Then your pandas is old or you are doing something not right. `replace` has `regex` option. The doc below. In `str` you always need `regex`.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html